# Confidence interval for a variable which is function of the coefficients of a linear regression, $\frac{\hat{\beta}_1}{\hat{\beta}_2}$

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model

Consider the following linear regression
$$Y = \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \epsilon$$

Can I compute a confidence interval for the estimate of the quantity ?
$$\frac{\beta_1}{\beta_2}$$

```r
# Load the mtcars dataset
data(mtcars)

# Fit a linear regression model with two predictor variables (e.g., mpg and hp)
lm_model <- lm(mpg ~ 0 + hp + wt, data = mtcars)

# Summarize the model
summary(lm_model)

Coefficients:
   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
hp -0.03394    0.03940  -0.861   0.3959   
wt  6.84045    1.89425   3.611   0.0011 **
```

I don't want to resort to the Delta method or bootstrap.

Comment: Do you mean confidence interval for $\beta_1 / \beta_2$ rather than $\hat{\beta}_1 / \hat{\beta}_2$? Also the example regression has an intercept, so it's $E(Y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2$. Usually it makes sense to include the intercept term.

Comment: This is a minor variation of [your previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/618834) and can be addressed in the same manner described there.  The question of how to estimate the ratio $\beta_1/\beta_2$ was recently posed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/625150/estimating-ratio-of-regression-coefficients.  For closely related threads (which likely already have answers) see [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=nonlinear+regression+confidence+answers%3A1).

Comment: Why *not* use the Delta method or the bootstrap?

Comment: @jbowman: If $\beta_2$ is close to zero, that can be imprecise, just use the profile likelihood as outlined in the post linked by whuber (and answered by me)

Comment: I don't want an intercept here

Comment: The intercept is not an issue.  When $X_1$ is constant, this is a model with a single explanatory variable $X_2$ and an intercept.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Jbowman suggested the Delta method and I don't know why you think this method is not suitable. You said that if $\beta_2$ close to zeto, the Delta method is imprecise, but this argument can apply also for any other methods (as $\beta_2 \to 0, \frac{\beta_1}{\beta_2} \to \infty$ and the confident interval becomes inevitably larger. By consequence, Delta method is still the most suitable methods.

Comment: @Julien Why don't you want to use the Delta method? Perhaps because of the argument of kjetilbhalvorsen ?

Comment: The delta method leads to symmetric confidence intervals which are not realistic here.  That would cause at least one of the tails to not have accurate non-coverage probability (e.g., 0.1 when you hope for 0.025 for a two-sided 0.95 CI).  If you fit a Bayesian regression you simply examine all the posterior draws of the ratio and construct an **exact** (aside from simulation error) uncertainty interval (highest posterior density interval or credible interval).

Comment: @NN2: The only way to find out is to try both ... (will try in an answer)